# Get requests return html code instead of real data

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, sequelize.js

My app is developed using Vue and Express.
There is a bug in my app that occurs only on Heroku or production environment, but not in localhost or development environment.

My app is on

Heroku: https://immense-refuge-12167.herokuapp.com/

github: https://github.com/powerseed/tabtracker_production

If you click on the "Browser" link at the top-left corner, an object named "response" will be printed on the console, like shown below:
[image]
It is a response returned from backend, and its `data` attribute is supposed to contain `song` objects that are returned from PostgresSQL database.

However, its `data` attribute contains `HTML` code instead, whose content is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel=stylesheet>
  <title>TabTracker</title>
  <link href=/static/css/app.a56f85525b4e670fc7da4a6aaae97f55.css rel=stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
<div id=app></div>
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.eb5d49c013eada509bc8.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.913b2b7edc7aedfb34fe.js></script></body></html>
```

I am wondering why... This bug doesn't occur on localhost. On localhost, the output is as shown below, which is correct.
[image]

Here is my code in client that send the `get` request to backend to get the `song` objects.

```
.
.
.
      async mounted() {
        const response = (await api.getSongs(this.search))
        this.songs = response.data;
        console.log({response})
        console.log(this.songs)
```

And the `api.getSongs()` method is:

(please ignore the `this.search` parameter, it is ignored for testing)

```
  const URL = "";

  getSongs(search){
    return axios.get(URL + "songs", {
      params:{
        search: search
      }
    });
  },
```

And in beckend, the method that handles the `get` request and retrieves from DB is:

```
app.get("/songs", async function (req, res) {
    try{
        let allSongs = await Song.findAll({
            limit: 10
        })
        res.send(allSongs);
    }
    catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send({
            error: 'An error occurred when getting all songs. '
        })
    }
})
```

It is weird as it works perfectly on localhost, but on Heroku this bug occurrs.

I think the DB is connected right, because the register and login functionalities work fine.

You can login only after you register. And they are both `post` request. So I guess the problem is about `get` only?

Besides, here is my `proxy` configuration:
`client/config/index.js`

```
module.exports = {
  dev: {
    // Paths
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {
      '/': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8081',
      }
    },
```

Thanks in advance!

Updated:

I have tried to add `headers: {Accept: 'application/json'}` and `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`, but the response is always `text/html`, which is different from my localhost, where it is always `application/json` even if I didn't add `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Comment: give a try adding `headers: {'content-type': 'application/json' }`

Comment: Could you tell me where to add it please? I just started learning front end. @upog

Comment: Axios takes a headers key in it's config object. You can add it there. Looks like this: `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`

Comment: I'm curious what the HTML is in the `data` key. Did you try copying and pasting into an html file and rendering it in your browser? It might be an error returned as HTML

Comment: @DanFletcher I updated this post to add the html code, please take a look.

Comment: @DanFletcher  Thanks but it doesn't work. I have changed it to `getSongs(search){
    return axios.get(URL + "songs", {
      params:{
        search: search
      },
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  },`

Comment: So looks like it's just returning your front-end app in the response. Not sure why though.

Comment: Headers are case sensitive, so make sure it's `Content-Type` not `content-type`. I don't see the header in the request on your heroku instance.

Comment: @DanFletcher How about now? I have changed to `getSongs(search){
    return axios.get(URL + "songs", {
      params:{
        search: search
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  },` But it seems stiil `text/html`. Looks like the it doesn't work... I did build and push again.

Comment: @DanFletcher https://github.com/powerseed/tabtracker_production This is the github repo of my app. I appreciate if you could take a look and help me solve this problem~

Comment: @powerseed I get a 404 when I try to visit the link

Comment: @DanFletcher Sry I have deleted the repo since the problem has been solved by Tito. Thank you all the same!

Comment: Awesome, glad you go it sorted out!

Answer (score 1):

Something wrong with express router. For any `GET` request your back-end(express) is responding with front page content.

Try directly hitting those urls in browser and observe the behavior:

```
https://immense-refuge-12167.herokuapp.com/songs?search=
https://immense-refuge-12167.herokuapp.com/allBookmarks?userId=3
```

I've tried with non existing url, which also resolved as `200 OK`. It should be `404 Not found`.

```
https://immense-refuge-12167.herokuapp.com/songs/invalid/url/test?search=
```

Comment: I tried but it seems not different... Could you give me more hints plz?

Comment: For that, I'll need your entry file(app.js or index.js) that sets the routing sequentially. Try adding some logger(morgan). Who is handing the `GET` request, Is it express's static middleware? Is there a caching server in front of your application? miss-configured and for this reason every `GET` request its responding with same content? Could be happend.

Comment: What you said is true on my localhost. When I type in `http://localhost:8080/songs/invalid/url/test?search=` it returned `Cannot GET /songs/invalid/url/test`. But on Heroku strang thing happens... Really don't know why...

Comment: github.com/powerseed/tabtracker_production This is the github repo of my app. I appreciate if you could take a look and help me solve this problem~

Comment: I think this declaration in app.js:91 is causing the problem. For any get request its sending index.html content. You should remove it. app.get(/.*/, function (req, res) { res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/index.html')) })

Comment: Oh my... Thank you so so so much! Please make it an answer I will accept it. You are a lifesaver! @Tito

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried add the accept headers to application/json?

```
return axios
  .get(URL + 'songs', {
    headers: { Accept: 'application/json' },
    params: { 
        search: search 
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error ' + error);
  });
```

Comment: I am trying this, will get back to you shortly. But it seems that Heroku always send the response as `text/html`, even if I have set `{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`. This is diffrerent from my local, where it is always `application/json`

Comment: Sry I doesn't work.. I have pushed it to Heroku, you can see it is still `text/html`

Comment: github.com/powerseed/tabtracker_production This is the github repo of my app. I appreciate if you could take a look and help me solve this problem~

Answer (score 0):

// try to use this after routes not before routes

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,  "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```